# How to restrict App Service by ip with Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, express

I have a ReactJS webapp and a backend webapp built with ExpressJS.
The are both hosted on Azure as different App services. Right now everyone can access any route for the Express app; every route returns some json data from Conteful API.

I'm trying to set a restriction in Azure for the Express app so only my React app can make requests to it.

I have found that you could do this by going to the Express app under Networking, there I have added a rule, and I have whitelisted the ip for the React app but I get a 403 now in my React app and it doesn't get any data back from Express.

Is there something more that I have to do?

I also discovered that my Express app and React app have the same Virtual ip addresses and also the same outbound ip addresses.

Does anyone know how I could fix this issue within Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to apply the security you want using ip addresses, because the same ip addresses may be [shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips) by many azure app services (yours and others too), and may change - e.g. if you upgrade to a different SKU.

Instead, I'd recommend putting your app services in an [Azure Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-overview) and using [Access Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions) to control access to the ExpressJS app service.

To be specific, I'd recommend:

1. creating an azure vnet with two subnets:

   - one for the back-end
   - one for the front-end, including a "Microsoft.Web" [Service Endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview)
2. put the ExpressJS app service [in the virtual network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-vnet-integration), in the back-end subnet
3. put the ReactJS app service in the front-end subnet
4. define Access Restrictions for the ExpressJS app service, allow traffic from the front-end subnet and disallowing all other incoming traffic
5. do not define any Access Restrictions for the ReactJS app service

End result:

1. internet traffic can reach the ReactJS app service, but *not* the ExpressJS app service.
2. Traffic from the ReactJS app service *can* reach the ExpressJS app service